# How do you get errors from overflowing int conversions in Go?

Tags: go, int

I'm looking for integer conversion functions resembling this:

```
func narrow(x int64) (int32, error) { ... }
```

In this example, the function would return `((int32)(x), nil)` if `x` fits into an `int32`, and `(nil, someError)` if it doesn't.

There seem to be a lot of [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) built into the language, but they all silently swallow overflows, rather than providing a reified error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversions do not report overflow.

Here's a function that handles positive and negative numbers:

```
func narrow(x int64) (int32, error) {
   y := int32(x)
   if int64(y) != x {
      return 0, errors.New("overflow")
   }
   return y, nil
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/eTGmFmo9Jw)